# [error]Facebook Developer Account is not creating New App ID for Cordova Hybrid App

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-facebook

I am new to Hybrid App's and new to FB integration. I am trying to create new App ID in FB developer account, the below page is showing. 
[After click on the create button also, the App ID is not creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4zPr.png)

the page is loading but app ID  is not creating. any one please help. and i need steps to create FB plugin in Hybrid Mobile Apps
Kindly do needful help...

I am following this guideline(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started)

Comment: I have the same problem, but it seems very rare for some reason.